# Database-level constraint to make sure product and tag belong to same account?

Tags: sqlite, foreign-keys, constraints

Suppose I have these tables:

```sql
CREATE TABLE "account" (
  "id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
  -- more fields
);

CREATE TABLE "product" (
  "id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  "accountId" INTEGER NOT NULL,
  -- more fields
  CONSTRAINT "fk_product_accountId" FOREIGN KEY("accountId") REFERENCES "account"("id") ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE "tag" (
  "id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  "accountId" INTEGER NOT NULL,
  -- more fields
  CONSTRAINT "fk_tag_accountId" FOREIGN KEY("accountId") REFERENCES "account"("id") ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE "product_tag" (
  "productId" INTEGER NOT NULL,
  "tagId" INTEGER NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY("productId", "tagId"),
  CONSTRAINT "fk_tag_productId" FOREIGN KEY("productId") REFERENCES "product"("id") ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT "fk_product_tagId" FOREIGN KEY("tagId") REFERENCES "tag"("id") ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

... in other words, an account can have products and tags associated with the account and can then associate these tags with those products.

Is there a way to define a constraint, at the database-level, that checks whether a `product_tag` combination is valid, i.e. whether the `tag` and `product` both belong to the same account, such that I can circumvent having to check this validity during an `INSERT` statement?

I thought about an additional column `accountId` in `product_tag`, but I don't think I can define multiple foreign keys on this, nor do I think this would actually check the constraint the way I intend.

Do `CHECK` constraints offer this level of complexity, perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
Account:
   AccountID int not null

Tag:
   AccountID int not null
   TagID int not null
   primary key (AccountID, TagID)
   foreign key (AccountID) references Account(AccountID)

Product:
   AccountID int not null
   ProductID int not null
   primary key (AccountID, ProductID)
   foreign key (AccountID) references Account(AccountID)

ProductTag:
   AccountID int not null,
   TagID int not null,
   ProductID int not null,
   primary key(AccountID, TagID, ProductID)
   foreign key(AccountID, TagID) references Tag(AccountID, TagID)
   foreign key(AccountID, ProductID) references Product(AccountID, ProductID)
```

Using composite keys instead of identity keys on `Tag` and `Product` enables us to do this.  I find using identity keys (surrogate keys) can have the effect of limiting the usefulness of constraints since the 'information' contained in the tables is more 'spread out', and constraints can only work on one or two tables, loosely speaking.  I really like this scenario as an example of this effect.  Using the first design would have forced us to use a trigger to enforce the rule.

I'm interested to see others' solutions on this...

Comment: This does indeed work the way I intended. Very nice. When I first tried this without using composite primary keys, it failed indeed. I didn't realize this could only work with composite keys. But, as you probably already expected, I'd rather keep using identity keys. :-) Great answer though! But I'm looking forward to other suggestions, as well. In the meantime I'll try out different combinations of your solution (perhaps with UNIQUE keys, etc.), to see if I can still get away with using identity keys (which will probably fail :-)).

Comment: Defining `UNIQUE` constraints on `product` and `tag` actually does appear to work as well! This allows me to keep using identity keys, unless I'm overlooking important issues here; I'll have to do some more testing to make sure I'm not.

Comment: It's true that these columns are allowed to be unique, but if you try to make ProductID/TagID the primary keys in these tables (instead of Account, Product composite key) you'll find you won't be able to have a foreign key to the composite non-key column combination (AccountID, TagID)...at least in SQL Server, not sure about SQLite.  Which is a strange limitation since, if ProductID is unique, certainly (AccountID, ProductID) is unique...

Comment: What I did, was keep the identity keys `id` in `product` and `tag` but also defined a `UNIQUE(id, accountId)` composite constraint for both tables. This allowed me to create the two (overlapping) foreign keys in `product_tag` (which you suggested in your answer) that I needed and this *does* actually enforce the constraints the way I intended. I'm not entirely sure if this is what you meant with your comment about it not working in SQL Server, but this setup actually works in sqlite. So thank you again for your suggestion! Very pleased I could get it to work.

Comment: Ohhhh fancy, I didn't think of that -- I'm not gonna lie, I've struggled with this exact scenario in the past and I had to settle with the composite key since I didn't figure that out...lol.  What's cool about this design is that now you can have other tables have an FK to only ProductID, for example, if they don't need the AccountID like ProductTag does.

Answer (score 1):

A foreign key constraint cares only about the column(s) that are part of the constraint, so the only way to check the account ID would be to make it part of all keys.

CHECK constraints must not contain subqueries, so they cannot be used for this.

The only way to handle this with the existing database structure is a trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER check_product_tag_same_account
BEFORE INSERT ON product_tag
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (SELECT accountId FROM product WHERE id = NEW.productId) !=
     (SELECT accountId FROM tag     WHERE id = NEW.tagId    )
BEGIN
    SELECT raise(FAIL, "account IDs do not match");
END;
```

Comment: Great. I'll give this a go as well. It actually looks similar to what I vaguely had in mind when I pondered on using `CHECK` constraints, while being unsure whether they allow for that complexity. Thank you for confirming that they don't and for your alternative solution, using a trigger.